# Windows audio service takes constantly over 10% of CPU

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio

`svchost` process on Windows 10 64b is taking 10-13% of CPU, all the time (older i5). If I stop service `Audiosrv` in that process (I'm using Process hacker) then it drops to zero. No sound is being played and it seems that is has no effect if there is audio being produced.

I tried reinstalling audio drivers (integrated sound card on motherboard and NVidia drivers for HDMI output). I also have an USB audio card, but I have never installed any drivers for it and it was working fine on Windows 7 64b and also on this Windows 10 64b for some time.

Any ideas how to fix this, so the service doesn't consume CPU power doing nothing? Current workaround is cumbersome - killing audio service and starting it only when I actually need audio. Also I think it has negative impact on games' performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. Excessive stress was caused by **Win10 Widgets** (Rainmeter). After unloading **volume widget** CPU stress from audio service disappeared.

If you want your **volume widget** (sure I am) change following line of text in `Volume-medium.ini` from `Update=1` to `Update=1000`.