# Windows8, taskhost.exe consuming CPU cycle for hours

Tags: windows-8, cpu, performance, tasks

I notice this process 'taskhost.exe' has been running continous on my laptop for hours.  It continues running even after I close the lid and reopen it.  I tried using processexplorer to see what it is running and it just says '!RtlUserThreadStart', what does that mean?  I already did a virus scan using MSE and found nothing.  What can I do to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: [analyze the CPU usage with WPRUI.exe/WPA](https://superuser.com/a/1203562/174557) . expand the stack of the taskhost.exe which has the large weight (%) ta the right side of the tabl.e

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did to solve this problem.

Go to action center->Maintenance, under automatic maintenance, click on change maintenance settings, set maintenance tasks daily at 11pm and uncheck 'allow scheduled maintenance to wake up my computer at the schedule time'

After running the laptop for almost a day, no more taskhost.exe taking up CPU cycles for hours.