# High CPU usage from explorer.exe shcore.dll!Ordinal247+0xc0

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, high-cpu-usage

I've been experiencing high cpu usage from explorer.exe in Windows 10 Pro since a while ago, and this specific dll function seems to be the culprit. Any idea what it's for? I couldn't find anything about it.

[image]

Stack:

[image]

After loading symbols:

[image]

Comment: [Use Windows Performance Toolkit](https://superuser.com/a/1203562/174557) to see the cause. Expand the stack of the Explorer.exe instead of svchost.exe

Comment: tried that, couldn't find anything with the Ordinal247 function

Comment: Ordinal247 means you haven't loaded debug symbols. if you need help with reading the ETL file, share the etl (compressed as zip via OneDrive)

Comment: If I load the symbols in Process Explorer the name changes to _WrapperThreadProc

Comment: this doesn't help, it is only a snapshot you see. use WPRUI to capture the cpu usage. Until you do this I'm out of this topic. Without the important information/data I can't help you.

Comment: Is it just high CPU usage or is it doing any IO?  Have had a similar prob in Win7 that I usually don't notice until it looking through my network disks.  How much memory is it using?  That was another characteristic of my prob.  With lower memory, it fill memory; w/higher memory would usually take long enough to fill that I'd notice it; with 10G network card, it would create a network storm -- which sometimes required puling network cord to regain control.  MS support eventually told me to upgrd to Win10 as fix. ;^/.  Interesting.

Answer (score -1):

As per [CPU usage -> explorer.exe / shcore.dll!Ordinal247+0xc0](https://superuser.com/questions/1299093/cpu-usage-explorer-exe-shcore-dllordinal2470xc0) :

> - Under Control Panel -> Keyboard properties, the Cursor Blink Rate was set on "None";
> - After we changed it to somewhere in the middle -> problem is gone.

[Screenshot of the Cursor Blink Rate Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ORG4.jpg)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1125931)

Comment: @Toto The essential parts of the answer are already included here! It's not a link-only answer as you accused it of being.

Answer (score -2):

Quoting the complete answer provided on [CPU usage -> explorer.exe / shcore.dll!Ordinal247+0xc0](https://superuser.com/questions/1299093/cpu-usage-explorer-exe-shcore-dllordinal2470xc0) :

> - Under Control Panel -> Keyboard properties, the Cursor Blink Rate was set on "None";
> - After we changed it to somewhere in the middle -> problem is gone.
> - [Screenshot of FIX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ORG4.jpg)
> - I don't know how/why, but this setting was problematic by us.