# CPU usage -> explorer.exe / shcore.dll!Ordinal247+0xc0

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, vmware

The virtual desktop infrastructure at our company consists of VMware Horizon with about 50 virtual machines running Windows 10 with the latest updates.

I have noticed on all user machines that the process `explorer.exe` is constantly using about 20% of the CPU (Thread `shcore.dll!Ordinal247+0xc0`).

[image: Explorer.exe shcore.dll]

After killing `explorer.exe` its CPU usage remains low for several minutes, but then the problem reoccurs.

#### Windows Performance Analyzer

[image: Screenshot from Explorer Stack from WPA]

#### Taskbar Settings

[image]

Comment: [analyze cpu usage with WPR(UI) and WPA](https://superuser.com/a/1203562/174557). Expand the stack of the explorer.exe which has the high Weight (%)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will do this today on one virtual machine and check it... If i would need help, can you please assist me then? I can send you what you need for analyzing... Thank you

Comment: I have done it with WPRUI, but I have a problem with analyzing it... which process makes the problem. Can you please assist me? I have uploaded ETL file - I can send you the link for download. Thank you

Comment: WPA picture shows that drawing 32Bit Icons (in Taskbar?) is causing the cpu usage. what are your taskbar settings (app grouping, small/large icons)? Which win10 build do you use (1607, 1703 or 1709)? And do you use last updates?

Comment: I have put the screenshot from our Taskbar settings above (screenshot). We are using Windows 10 Pro (Version 1709 / 16299.125). We are doing Windows Update every weekend.

Comment: 16299.125 is not the last version. install update [KB4074588 (OS Build 16299.248)](http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=KB4074588). This update includes GDI fixes. look if it is faster now.

Comment: Just want to give you info, that problem was resolved. Your advise help me a lot, with icons in taskbar. I have notice, that some icons in taskbar stayed highlighted for no reason (no notification on Skype...). Problem was solved with this strange setting -> Control panel / Keyoboard / Cursor blink rate - this was set on "None" and after we changed it to somewhere in the middle -> problem is gone. I don't know how/why, but this setting was problematic by us. Thank you very much with analyzing ETL file that I have send.

Comment: ok, post a detailed answer on all steps (and pictures) you did to fix the issue

Comment: post the picture in an answer, not edit your question. Later you can accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Under Control Panel -> Keyboard properties, the Cursor Blink Rate was set on "None" and after we changed it to somewhere in the middle -> problem is gone.

[image: Screenshot of FIX]

I don't know how/why, but this setting was problematic by us.

Comment: How did you reach the conclusion that this is the issue?

Comment: This has solved my CPU usage issue as well. The symptoms wer identical, the thread view of explorer.exe and all. However, the persistent application notification highlight on the taskbar remains -- interesting that we both have that bug too. This highlight bug, an issue in its own right, has persisted for at least half a year for me, with regular updates.