# Explorer.exe taking high CPU usage on Surface Pro 4 - ETL analysis is done

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, cpu-usage, high-cpu-usage

following a very similar thread [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1278678/high-cpu-usage-from-explorer-exe-shcore-dllordinal2470xc0) - I am posting the screenshot of ETL analysis in Windows Performance Analyzer.

EDIT: ETL file is [here as RAR file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Av62WUuxYHqLoTHH7i3-W7nk0ffc) captured on Windows version 1709 OS Build 16299.192 using today's WPR (just downloaded) and Analyzer 10.0.16299.91

Follows is the screenshot shows like 20+ levels of stack of what is causing it... I am afraid I am not sure how to figure out the cause from various function names being called...
I've also completed loading the symbols, but they dont seem to help make sense of what causes it.

[image: ETL CPU Sampled analysis stack]

I've gone up to like row 48 in stack depth, and still not a clue...

Can anyone please help?

Comment: expand the view more. it doesn't show the issue. something with trayicon

Comment: also zip the file, download speed is so slow that it takes hours to get it for me.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Sorry! I did not think of trying to zip it... https://1drv.ms/u/s!Av62WUuxYHqLoTHH7i3-W7nk0ffc its now about 100MB.  I tried drilling deeper, deepest I see is `Line #, Process, Stack, Count, Weight (in view) (ms), TimeStamp (s), % Weight
45, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!ExfAcquirePushLockExclusiveEx<itself>, 497, 497.128562, , 0.08` - again, not helpful

Comment: Another branch gets as deep as `ntoskrnl.exe!MmCommitSessionMappedView` - also no clue what it means

Comment: update the Windows to 16299.251: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4090913/march5-2018kb4090913osbuild16299-251

Comment: @magicandre1981 Why? is there a bug in current version? I disabled updates because I dont want the meltdown/Spectre fixes to slow down my IO by ~20%...

Comment: without UEFI fix, the meltdown fixes are not activated. before 16299.2xx there were GDI issues which causes slow drawings. Maybe this also caused your issue. so install last update and look what happens

Comment: Is that suggestion based on insight from the wpr file analysis? I will try now, will update

Comment: a bit. I see a lot of Win32k GDI calls and I know that MS fixed some GDI issues, which caused TortoiseMerge issues. So give it a try.

Comment: @magicandre1981 you were spot on - been running a few hours after upgrade and no issue anymore, finally the Surface is not spitting hot air all the time :) strange..

Comment: nice to hear this. I posted [it as answer](https://superuser.com/a/1301327/174557) so that you can [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Analyzing he ETL with Windows Performance Analyzer (WPA.exe)](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-42-WPT-CPU-Analysis) shows a lot of GDI calls in stack

[image]

In the Fall Creators update v1709, Microsoft [broke GDI and made it slower compared to older Windows 10 Versions, which also caused slow downs to other tools like TortoiseMerge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46913696/1466046).

The fix is to install the last Updates to update Windows 10 to at least 16299.2xx which includes a fix for that issue. You still use the older 16299.192 which suffers the slowness.

As of writing on 07 March 2018, the [last Windows 10 Update for 1709 is KB4090913](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4090913/march5-2018kb4090913osbuild16299-251). [Download and install this update](http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=KB4090913) to fix the CPU issue.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely made me learn how to diagnose lagging things like that. How, in the future, am I supposed to infer as to the source of the issue? Say if you didnt happen to know that MS happen to fix something related to GDI, how would you/I go about something like this in the future?

Comment: Without knowing about this GDI fix I would also not be able to see it. Lets wait what Microsoft damages wit hthe next version which is released in 1 month (Version 1803)

Comment: I am inclined to leave updates turned off and not let Ms introduce bugs like that again, and only update manually if I have a good reason to.

Comment: This is why I'm still at Windows 8.1 and avoid this  construction area called Windows 10.