# Windows explorer.exe lag spikes

Tags: windows-explorer, lag

Similar question to previous [post](https://superuser.com/questions/1300254/explorer-exe-taking-high-cpu-usage-on-surface-pro-4-etl-analysis-is-done) a few years ago.

Build 19041.450

[Trace](https://mega.nz/file/TAcw1aTA#qFCthAQZwzNjWP1yEnTBq2BDX26KdGBJW5hM25XIXhg)

Problem: Occasional massive lag spikes on explorer.exe. Never happens after a fresh reboot, but happens with increasing frequency as system is up. Start menu also affected. Problem is solved by restarting explorer.exe, until time passes and the same thing happens.

[ctraynotify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ima7K.png)

At first I thought this could be the GDI tray issue again, but doesn't make sense with this version of windows. Anything else?

A clean install was tried which did not solve this problem, so maybe some sort of device driver funkiness (all updates were applied) or base installed software (Photoshop open "seems" to make the problem worse).

System does not seem to be starved of CPU (Ryzen 3950x), memory (64 GB), or IO (2 TB NVMe).

Comment: Look in Reliability History (Security and Maintenance) and see if there are Windows Explorer stopped working errors.

Comment: Teracopy faulted a few times, but the problems occurred before teracopy was installed.

Description
Faulting application name: teracopy.exe, version: 3.2.6.0, time stamp: 0x59e4905e
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.19041.423, time stamp: 0x09cf3bbe
Exception code: 0x0eedfade
Fault offset: 0x00129962
Faulting process id: 0x8744
Faulting application start time: 0x01d680be391c47fa
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\TeraCopy\teracopy.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
...

Comment: There are a couple of reasons why Explorer slows. That is why I asked about reliability history for Explorer

Answer (score 0):

Tentatively solved(?) by totally uninstalling and reinstalling display drivers (Display Driver Uninstaller) without a network connection.

Unsure why this needed to be done, given a totally pristine Windows install and no other graphics card having been used on this computer. I blame Windows Update as usual.

For now, I think I will run DDU on any system that I deploy with a discrete graphics card.