# Computer stopped working hard oversnight

Tags: windows-10, cpu, performance, lenovo-laptop, cpu-usage

I'm dealing with a strange computer problem at the moment. My computer's CPU suddenly goes to 100% super fast. Im monitoring it and things that usually only take 10-30% CPU take 100%. On top of that my core temps are staying low and my fan is not running fast at all. It is as if my PC is not giving programs enough. Baffled by this and can't find anything online (no matter what I search I find 'computer cpu high with loud fan and hot pc). Thanks for any help. MY PC is a Lenovo Z70 gaming PC with Core i5 and Nvidia Geforce. I keep my pc in high power mode.

Comment: What processes are running? Which ones are running high cpu? Have you restarted the computer? Is your computer installing updates? You are are eyes and ears here, and you've provided very little functional information besides the basic statement of the primary symptoms. We need further details to resolve this.

Comment: Im not running anything, nothing seems out of the ordinary. svchost is doing what it normally does. MY CPU is in like 12% when Im doing nothing. But if I start anything it goes up to 100% really fast.

Comment: Which service(s) is the offending scvhost running? If you right-click on the scvhost entry that runs high one option is to view the associated service(s).

Comment: [analyze CPU usage with WPRUI/WPA](https://superuser.com/a/1203562/174557)