# High memory and CPU usage, is there a way to diagnose and fix?

Tags: windows-10, memory, cpu, performance

I'm a 16 year old developer on what I see as a "decent" computer for my age and for what I do. My computer currently has 8GB of RAM and an Intel Core i3

I do a lot for a 16 year old, I program inside of Visual Studio which takes a lot of memory, not so much CPU, I program inside of Visual Studio code and I browse a fair bit. Taking a look at my stats now and again the resources on my computer are fairly high, especially the memory.

I can't remember the last time I looked at my resources and seen my memory under 60%, and what what it is, I've always thought the processor was the thing lacking for me, I mean 8GB memory is a lot isn't it? Most computers I see only have a maximum of 4GB ram.

The problem is, my resources are always high, and my PC feels sluggish when developing, if I close all my open applications it will resume being fast and responsive. The computer goes okay for around 6 seconds then will have a 2-5 second bit of sluggishness.

Even the smallest of applications seem to be taking up massive amounts of CPU, once one application finishes with the 5 slices of my CPU (Thinking of pizza here) it gives it to another application to use around 20% CPU, why are my applications using so much CPU? Is this a hardware problem or something else?

My task manager:

[image]

Here is an image of my specs:

[image]

These are:

- Intel i3-2120 CPU
- 8 gigs DDR3
- 665 MHZ
- ASuStek motherboard
- NVIDIA GT710 with 1gig ram
- 500 gig Seagate 3.5" 7200 RPM hard drive

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm voting to close, as the question  is to broad.   I would point out the following - you are using an old hard drive - if the system is disk bound - and I suspect - but based on information can't know - it is - replacing it with an SSD will offer a massive speed boost - especially if its not CPU bound.     Also, this system is fairly old (Circa 2012, and most new developer systems would start at 8 gigs of RAM, with 32 gigs being fairly common).   Your CPU is slow, and only has 2 cores - i3's are fairly entry level for developers - i5 and i7 is more common.

Comment: A typical "new" system will have in the order of twice the CPU performance.   Having memory below 60% is a red herring - most OS's cache stuff in unused memory inflating this figure.    Based on the info provided its not possible to suggest if its a hardware or software issue, but I'd imagine its hardware.

Comment: I saw many hardware's with lower cpu/ram abilities run windows 10 and visual studio without such issues (your CPU is 3.30 GHz based on your model, the 665MHz is probably for your RAM?). I think there is some software issue (maybe a virus or malware) which uses your resources. I suggest you install a new instance of windows in another drive and test situations

Comment: [analyze the CPU usage with WPRUI/WPA](https://superuser.com/a/1203562/174557). For high memory usage provide [RAMMap](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/rammap) pictures

Answer (score -1):

Let see if you don't have any windows update running in background.
I think there is no magic or If your computer is running well btw it must not be related to hardware.
Try to find out processes using CPU (run msconfig to disable some background application launched at startup)

Also, the bottleneck of your PC is the Mechanical Hard Drive, if he is faulty it can slow down your PC. Try putting a SSD into your system the gain would be appreciable :)