# task scheduler and search indexer consuming CPU on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, cpu-usage, windows-search, windows-task-scheduler

Microsoft Windows Search Indexer and 'Service Host : Task Scheduler' are consuming big portion of the CPU, something that i have noticed is that they use the same amount of CPU most of the time
For Example :
Task Host Scheduler :28.1

Windows Search Indexer : 28.1

and they change but have the same CPU most of the time.

Also, Windows Search service is stuck on 'Starting'.

Answer (score 0):

Windows performance toolkit can help us see the cpu usage on details. Load the symbols before you analyze it.
There will be stack,thread etc shown under process, which account for high cpu.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4847.install-the-windows-performance-toolkit-wpt.aspx

Comment: the idea is correct, but your "answer" has low quality. [Here is a detailed answer to analyze the CPU usage](https://superuser.com/a/1203562/174557)