# Explorer.exe RAM and CPU usage keeps increasing with no limit until I terminate the process

Tags: windows-10, performance, windows-explorer, cpu-usage

I'm running Windows 10 Pro 1903 (18362.418) on an Acer A515-51G-72DB laptop. The only thing I think is interacting with explorer.exe is ClassicStartMenu.

I'm not sure when was the starting point, but recently, explorer.exe started showing the behavior above to the point that I have to keep killing the process every 15 minutes or so for Windows to remain usable. Also this only happens when an explorer window is open.

I did follow the steps described [HERE](https://superuser.com/a/1203562/1112751) to generate and analyze an ETL file with Windows Performance Toolkit (results below), but I don't know what to do with my findings.

Here's the output (filtered to explorer.exe) as raw data (sorted by Weight%), screenshots [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggbPr.png), [(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzL8W.png), [(3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVX6B.png) and [WPAPK](https://www.solidfiles.com/v/3PAWkrQvQk88Y):

```
Line #, Process, Stack, Function, Count, Weight (in view) (ms), TimeStamp (s), % Weight
1, explorer.exe (8212), , , 32667, 32.501,176802, , 4,97
2, , n/a, , 16348, 16.260,730167, , 2,49
3, , [Root], , 16319, 16.240,446635, , 2,48
4, ,   |- ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart, , 16240, 16.161,338732, , 2,47
5, ,   |    kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk, , 16240, 16.161,338732, , 2,47
6, ,   |    |- SHCore.dll!_WrapperThreadProc, , 12829, 12.776,373921, , 1,95
7, ,   |    |    |- shell32.dll!CChangeNotify::s_ThreadProc, , 11462, 11.413,706151, , 1,75
8, ,   |    |    |    shell32.dll!CChangeNotify::_MessagePump, , 11462, 11.413,706151, , 1,75
9, ,   |    |    |    |- user32.dll!DispatchMessageWorker, , 11319, 11.271,266149, , 1,72
10, ,   |    |    |    |    user32.dll!UserCallWinProcCheckWow, , 11319, 11.271,266149, , 1,72
11, ,   |    |    |    |    shell32.dll!CChangeNotify::s_WndProc, , 11319, 11.271,266149, , 1,72
12, ,   |    |    |    |    |- shell32.dll!CAnyAlias::v_SendNotification, , 10832, 10.785,277243, , 1,65
13, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |- shell32.dll!ReparseRelativeIDListInternal, , 6437, 6.411,484738, , 0,98
14, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |- shell32.dll!CFolderShortcut::ParseDisplayName, , 2144, 2.134,065200, , 0,33
15, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- windows.storage.dll!CRegFolder::ParseDisplayName, , 2055, 2.045,744996, , 0,31
16, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- windows.storage.dll!CKnownFoldersFolder::ParseDisplayName, , 1624, 1.615,865696, , 0,25
17, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- windows.storage.dll!CKnownFoldersFolder::_EnumFolders, , 1390, 1.383,063595, , 0,21
18, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- windows.storage.dll!CKnownFoldersFilter::ShouldShowKnownFolder, , 772, 767,444117, , 0,12
19, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- windows.storage.dll!CKnownFoldersFilter::IsKnownFolderSetByPolicy, , 649, 644,714715, , 0,10
20, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- windows.storage.dll!kfapi::GetFolderRedirectionCapabilities, , 648, 643,714715, , 0,10
21, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- windows.storage.dll!CLastStateKeeper::Init, , 335, 333,309012, , 0,05
22, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- windows.storage.dll!CLastStateKeeper::IsTSAsyncLogonPolicyEnabled, , 145, 144,057300, , 0,02
23, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- windows.storage.dll!CLastStateKeeper::_IsVDIRoleInstalled, , 110, 109,361699, , 0,02
24, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- KernelBase.dll!RegOpenKeyExW, , 70, 69,818499, , 0,01
25, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    KernelBase.dll!RegOpenKeyExInternalW, , 70, 69,818499, , 0,01
26, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- KernelBase.dll!LocalBaseRegOpenKey, , 69, 68,818699, , 0,01
27, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntdll.dll!ZwOpenKeyEx, , 55, 54,645398, , 0,01
28, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd, , 48, 47,674998, , 0,01
29, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    ntoskrnl.exe!NtOpenKeyEx, , 48, 47,674998, , 0,01
30, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    ntoskrnl.exe!CmOpenKey, , 48, 47,674998, , 0,01
31, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!ObOpenObjectByName, , 47, 46,668899, , 0,01
32, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    ntoskrnl.exe!ObOpenObjectByNameEx, , 47, 46,668899, , 0,01
33, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!ObpLookupObjectName, , 35, 34,627699, , 0,01
34, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!CmpParseKey, , 33, 32,668099, , 0,00
35, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!CmpDoParseKey, , 31, 30,769798, , 0,00
36, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!CmpPerformCompleteKcbCacheLookup, , 14, 13,800897, , 0,00
37, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!CmpPerformCompleteKcbCacheLookup<itself>, CmpPerformCompleteKcbCacheLookup, 12, 11,801598, , 0,00
38, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!ExReleasePushLockEx, ExReleasePushLockEx, 1, 0,999700, 2.110,246868500, 0,00
39, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!ExAcquirePushLockSharedEx, ExAcquirePushLockSharedEx, 1, 0,999599, 2.164,792446299, 0,00
40, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!CmpCheckOpenAccessOnKeyBody, , 6, 5,989800, , 0,00
41, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!SeAccessCheck, , 2, 1,999700, , 0,00
42, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    ntoskrnl.exe!AdminlessTelemetryEnabled, , 2, 1,999700, , 0,00
43, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    ntoskrnl.exe!SeCodeIntegrityQueryPolicyInformation, , 2, 1,999700, , 0,00
44, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!_guard_dispatch_icall, _guard_dispatch_icall, 1, 0,999900, 2.147,543414400, 0,00
45, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- CI.dll!CipQueryPolicyInformation, , 1, 0,999800, , 0,00
46, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    CI.dll!SIPolicyQueryPolicyInformation, , 1, 0,999800, , 0,00
47, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |  , SIPolicyQueryPolicyInformation, 1, 0,999800, 2.123,418773900, 0,00
48, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!ExReleaseResourceLite, , 2, 1,998800, , 0,00
49, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!ExReleaseResourceLite<itself>, ExReleaseResourceLite, 1, 0,999600, 2.111,632910600, 0,00
50, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!ExpReleaseResourceSharedForThreadLite, ExpReleaseResourceSharedForThreadLite, 1, 0,999200, 2.111,511848600, 0,00
51, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!SeOpenObjectAuditAlarmWithTransaction, SeOpenObjectAuditAlarmWithTransaction, 1, 0,999900, 2.154,097251400, 0,00
52, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!CmpCheckOpenAccessOnKeyBody<itself>, CmpCheckOpenAccessOnKeyBody, 1, 0,991400, 2.109,145310700, 0,00
53, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!CmpDereferenceKeyControlBlock, CmpDereferenceKeyControlBlock, 2, 2,081600, , 0,00
54, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!CmpComputeComponentHashes, CmpComputeComponentHashes, 2, 1,898401, , 0,00
55, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!CmpLockRegistry, , 1, 1,012500, , 0,00
56, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    ntoskrnl.exe!ExAcquireResourceSharedLite, , 1, 1,012500, , 0,00
57, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |  , ExAcquireResourceSharedLite, 1, 1,012500, 2.140,612770600, 0,00
58, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!CmpLockKcbStackShared, CmpLockKcbStackShared, 1, 1,000100, 2.140,605104100, 0,00
59, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!CmpUnlockKcb, , 1, 1,000000, , 0,00
60, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    ntoskrnl.exe!ExReleasePushLockEx, , 1, 1,000000, , 0,00
61, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |  , ExReleasePushLockEx, 1, 1,000000, 2.127,105902200, 0,00
62, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!CmpCreateKeyBody, , 1, 0,999800, , 0,00
63, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    ntoskrnl.exe!ObpAllocateObject, , 1, 0,999800, , 0,00
64, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    ntoskrnl.exe!ExAllocatePoolWithTag, , 1, 0,999800, , 0,00
65, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    ntoskrnl.exe!ExAllocateHeapPool, , 1, 0,999800, , 0,00
66, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |  , ExAllocateHeapPool, 1, 0,999800, 2.115,067369600, 0,00
67, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!CmpRecordParseStartingKcb, CmpRecordParseStartingKcb, 1, 0,999700, 2.160,912023700, 0,00
68, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!CmpUnlockHashEntryByKcb, , 1, 0,999600, , 0,00
69, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    ntoskrnl.exe!ExReleasePushLockEx, , 1, 0,999600, , 0,00
70, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |  , ExReleasePushLockEx, 1, 0,999600, 2.132,724940400, 0,00
71, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!CmpDoParseKey<itself>, CmpDoParseKey, 1, 0,987400, 2.158,108737100, 0,00
72, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!CmpCallCallBacksEx, , 1, 1,000101, , 0,00
73, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    WdFilter.sys!<PDB not found>, , 1, 1,000101, , 0,00
74, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |  , ?, 1, 1,000101, 2.141,272666100, 0,00
75, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!CmpParseKey<itself>, CmpParseKey, 1, 0,898200, 2.145,898431800, 0,00
76, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!SeAccessCheckWithHint, , 2, 1,959600, , 0,00
77, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!SeCodeIntegrityQueryPolicyInformation, , 1, 0,999200, , 0,00
78, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    CI.dll!CipQueryPolicyInformation, , 1, 0,999200, , 0,00
79, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    CI.dll!SIPolicyQueryPolicyInformation, , 1, 0,999200, , 0,00
80, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    CI.dll!SIPolicyQueryWindowsLockdownMode, , 1, 0,999200, , 0,00
81, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    CI.dll!SIPolicyIsPolicyActive, , 1, 0,999200, , 0,00
82, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |  , SIPolicyIsPolicyActive, 1, 0,999200, 2.118,200509499, 0,00
83, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!SeAccessCheckWithHintWithAdminlessChecks, SeAccessCheckWithHintWithAdminlessChecks, 1, 0,960400, 2.145,237391800, 0,00
84, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!SepCreateAccessStateFromSubjectContext, SepCreateAccessStateFromSubjectContext, 3, 2,999199, , 0,00
85, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!ObpCreateHandle, , 3, 2,994001, , 0,00
86, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!ObpIncrementHandleCountEx, , 1, 1,008701, , 0,00
87, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    ntoskrnl.exe!ExAcquirePushLockExclusiveEx, , 1, 1,008701, , 0,00
88, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |  , ExAcquirePushLockExclusiveEx, 1, 1,008701, 2.160,897378200, 0,00
89, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!ObpCreateHandle<itself>, ObpCreateHandle, 1, 1,000400, 2.117,312571800, 0,00
90, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!ExAcquirePushLockExclusiveEx, ExAcquirePushLockExclusiveEx, 1, 0,984900, 2.162,383767800, 0,00
91, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!ExpInterlockedPopEntrySListEnd, ExpInterlockedPopEntrySListEnd, 2, 1,999700, , 0,00
92, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!ObOpenObjectByNameEx<itself>, ObOpenObjectByNameEx, 2, 1,998500, , 0,00
93, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!SepDeleteAccessState, SepDeleteAccessState, 1, 1,049600, 2.109,194289800, 0,00
94, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!SeSetLearningModeObjectInformation, SeSetLearningModeObjectInformation, 1, 1,000200, 2.162,292804200, 0,00
95, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!CmpReleaseShutdownRundown, , 1, 1,006099, , 0,00
96, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    ntoskrnl.exe!KiLeaveCriticalRegionUnsafe, , 1, 1,006099, , 0,00
97, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    ntoskrnl.exe!KiCheckForKernelApcDelivery, , 1, 1,006099, , 0,00
98, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    ntoskrnl.exe!KiDeliverApc, , 1, 1,006099, , 0,00
99, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    ntoskrnl.exe!EtwpStackWalkApc, , 1, 1,006099, , 0,00
100, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    ntoskrnl.exe!EtwpTraceStackWalk, , 1, 1,006099, , 0,00
101, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    ntoskrnl.exe!RtlWalkFrameChain, , 1, 1,006099, , 0,00
102, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    ntoskrnl.exe!RtlpWalkFrameChain, , 1, 1,006099, , 0,00
103, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |  , RtlpWalkFrameChain, 1, 1,006099, 2.165,101546299, 0,00
104, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!KiSystemServiceUser, KiSystemServiceUser, 3, 2,989499, , 0,00
105, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntdll.dll!ZwOpenKeyEx<itself>, ZwOpenKeyEx, 3, 2,981201, , 0,00
106, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!KiSystemServiceExit, KiSystemServiceExit, 1, 0,999700, 2.143,828675599, 0,00
107, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- KernelBase.dll!ConstructKernelKeyPath, , 14, 14,173301, , 0,00
108, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    ntdll.dll!NtQueryKey, , 14, 14,173301, , 0,00
109, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd, , 6, 6,057602, , 0,00
110, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    ntoskrnl.exe!NtQueryKey, , 6, 6,057602, , 0,00
111, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!CmpCallCallBacksEx, , 3, 3,070602, , 0,00
112, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!CmpCallCallBacksEx<itself>, CmpCallCallBacksEx, 2, 2,070701, , 0,00
113, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- WdFilter.sys!<PDB not found>, ?, 1, 0,999901, 2.111,836947000, 0,00
114, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!ObReferenceObjectByHandle, , 2, 1,999000, , 0,00
115, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    ntoskrnl.exe!ObpReferenceObjectByHandleWithTag, , 2, 1,999000, , 0,00
116, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |  , ObpReferenceObjectByHandleWithTag, 2, 1,999000, , 0,00
117, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!ExAcquireRundownProtection, ExAcquireRundownProtection, 1, 0,988000, 2.110,153867400, 0,00
118, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!KiSystemServiceUser, KiSystemServiceUser, 4, 4,045300, , 0,00
119, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntdll.dll!NtQueryKey<itself>, NtQueryKey, 2, 2,070999, , 0,00
120, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!KiSystemServiceStart, KiSystemServiceStart, 1, 0,999900, 2.153,496947400, 0,00
121, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!KiDpcInterrupt, , 1, 0,999500, , 0,00
122, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    ntoskrnl.exe!KxDispatchInterrupt, , 1, 0,999500, , 0,00
123, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    ntoskrnl.exe!SwapContext, , 1, 0,999500, , 0,00
124, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    ntoskrnl.exe!EtwTraceContextSwap, , 1, 0,999500, , 0,00
125, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    ntoskrnl.exe!EtwpLogContextSwapEvent, , 1, 0,999500, , 0,00
126, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    ntoskrnl.exe!EtwpStackTraceDispatcher, , 1, 0,999500, , 0,00
127, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    ntoskrnl.exe!EtwpTraceStackWalk, , 1, 0,999500, , 0,00
128, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    ntoskrnl.exe!RtlWalkFrameChain, , 1, 0,999500, , 0,00
129, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    ntoskrnl.exe!RtlpWalkFrameChain, , 1, 0,999500, , 0,00
130, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |  , RtlpWalkFrameChain, 1, 0,999500, 2.158,223313600, 0,00
131, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- KernelBase.dll!RegOpenKeyExInternalW<itself>, RegOpenKeyExInternalW, 1, 0,999800, 2.154,278650500, 0,00
132, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- KernelBase.dll!RegQueryValueExW, , 29, 28,654801, , 0,00
133, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    KernelBase.dll!LocalBaseRegQueryValue, , 29, 28,654801, , 0,00
134, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntdll.dll!ZwQueryValueKey, , 27, 26,654702, , 0,00
135, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd, , 22, 21,655303, , 0,00
136, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!NtQueryValueKey, , 21, 20,749203, , 0,00
137, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!CmQueryValueKey, , 11, 10,937601, , 0,00
138, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!CmpAttachToRegistryProcess, , 5, 5,050100, , 0,00
139, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    ntoskrnl.exe!KiStackAttachProcess, , 5, 5,050100, , 0,00
140, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |  , KiStackAttachProcess, 5, 5,050100, , 0,00
141, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!CmpDetachFromRegistryProcess, , 3, 2,886999, , 0,00
142, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    ntoskrnl.exe!KiUnstackDetachProcess, , 3, 2,886999, , 0,00
143, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!KiUnstackDetachProcess<itself>, KiUnstackDetachProcess, 2, 2,001100, , 0,00
144, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!KiMoveApcState, KiMoveApcState, 1, 0,885899, 2.112,045007099, 0,00
145, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!CmpLockRegistry, CmpLockRegistry, 2, 2,000402, , 0,00
146, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!CmQueryValueKey<itself>, CmQueryValueKey, 1, 1,000100, 2.123,979445900, 0,00
147, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!CmpCallCallBacks, , 2, 1,998201, , 0,00
148, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    ntoskrnl.exe!CmpCallCallBacksEx, , 2, 1,998201, , 0,00
149, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!CmpCallCallBacksEx<itself>, CmpCallCallBacksEx, 1, 1,000400, 2.115,535365800, 0,00
150, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!ExpInterlockedPopEntrySListEnd, ExpInterlockedPopEntrySListEnd, 1, 0,997801, 2.112,055010500, 0,00
151, ,   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |- ntoskrnl.exe!CmPostCallbackNotification, , 2, 1,993000, , 0,00
---------------------------CROPPED---------------------------
```

Also here's what Sysinternals' Process Explorer gives as "Starting Adress" when looking at Properties>Threads in explorer.exe for the thread with highest CPU usage:

```
shcore.dll!Ordinal172+0x30
```

My guess is that this "Ordinal172" is key to the solution, as I have stumbled upon similar questions, but with other Ordinals.